# How to overwrite the inputs in Retropie for specific emulator/rom?

Tags: retropie, input-device

[image]

I have a Pi3 flashed with Retropie connected to a Switch Controller via USB.

[image]

The controller mapping seems off.

I can't seem to play in KOF97 properly. 
I want to remapped it.

Right now it mapped to :

```
(X) - big kick
(Y) - big punch 
(A) - small kick
(B) - small punch
```

I want to overwrite to :

```
(X) - big punch
(Y) - small punch 
(A) - big kick
(B) - small kick
```

**How would one configure a specific inputs for specific emulator or rom ?**

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to start the game and then bring up RetroArch's RGUI menu using <kbd>Select</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

On that menu use D-pad <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> buttons to highlight `Controls` and press <kbd>A</kbd> to open that. Then select `Port 1 Controls`.

Use the D-pad <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> buttons to highlight the control line you want, then use the D-pad <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> buttons to change which controller button is assigned to that line.

If the names on the left don't make sense see [Mapping gamepad controls in RetroPie (for MAME2003 arcade games)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/111334/2955) which may help (just ignore the MAME stuff).

You must save the configuration back at the RGUI menu.

Some of this is explained at [RetroArch Controller Configuration](https://retropie.org.uk/docs/RetroArch-Configuration/) which covers global, per-emulator ("system-specific") and per-game ("ROM-specific") remapping.